# In EE 1.13 clearing cache from Admin does not actually cleans the cache

Tags: magento, caching, redis, magento-1.13

In My latest magento setup when I am clearing the cache from admin it does not clear the cache   and my changes are not reflecting in frontend.

When I clear the cache directories from server my changes starts reflecting.

Is there anything that admin cache clean functionality is not working.

Comment: Hi, In 1.13 EE version cache is cleared only for changed data. Check this page for details http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-and-ee-113-documentation-home

Comment: Marceli thanks for the details but the issue is coming mainly for CMS data such as static pages and blocks. Then what can we do in this situation? Please share if any suggestions

Comment: Well the best way for now is to contact magento support as you are working with EE version. I remember when I was talking to them they said to use 1.12 for now as 1.13 is not stable :( They recommend to use it only for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento EE support does have a patch for this. The patch number is 1498_EE_1.13.0.0_v1

The patch adds a public function in app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php

```
public function flushCache()
{
    Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()->flush();
    return $this;
}
```

And also changes an observer method in app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/etc/config.xml

```
             <observers>
                 <enterprise_pagecache>
                     <class>enterprise_pagecache/observer</class>
-                        <method>cleanCache</method>
+                        <method>flushCache</method>
                 </enterprise_pagecache>
             </observers>
         </adminhtml_cache_flush_all>
```